# Further away from .... than

Tags: meaning

> A is 50 miles further away from B than C.

Does this mean distance between A and B is 50 miles Or between A and C is 50 miles.
I am really confused. please help.

Comment: Nothing says C and B are in the same direction from A. Neither of you options is right. But this is a math question.

Comment: A is 50 miles further away from B than it is from C. So if A to C is 20 miles, then A to B is 70 miles.

Comment: It can't be resolved, because this poorly-expressed sentence is ambiguous: it leaves out a key part of the sentence. "Than C" could mean *either* "than C is from B" (in other words, the distances from B are being compared), *or* "than A is from C" (ie comparing the distances from A).

Comment: You are confused because, as @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica says, the statemenr is ambiguous. I'm a native speaker and I don't know exactly what the writer intended either. The context may make it clear, but it might not.

Comment: D[A-C] = x ////// D[A-B] = x + 50 {units: miles}

Answer (score 1):

The sentence doesn't say that the distance between any of the two points is 50 miles. The distance between A and B is 50 miles more than the distance between A and C.

For example, if the distance between A and C is 100 miles, then the distance between A and B will be 50 miles more, which makes it 150 miles.